# Encontrar un camino en un grafo(no tiene que ser ni el mas corto ni el mas largo)

Tags: java, graph

Mi problema es que no puedo utilizar como tal el algoritmo de Dijkstra ya que es un grafo dirigido sin pesos es decir que cualquier camino pesa lo mismo. Me están pidiendo que encuentre un camino da igual cual. y pongo que me de el camino de 5 a 5 y me sale [5,2,5] cuando en el Set de vértices del vértice 2 no esta el vértice 5.

En la linea 100 hay un if que supuestamente deberia hacer que si me piden que encuentre un camino que va del vertice al mismo vertice simplemente se termine el codigo, pero no lo hace y ademas me añade el 2 que tengo en el camino del 5 al 5 y no se porque.

Estoy haciendo una especie de algoritmo de Dijkstra pero sin tener que ponerme a calcular los pesos de cada camino. El método con el que tengo duda es el onePath.

```
package practicaSimples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph<V> {
    
    private Map<V, Set<V>> adjacencyList;
    private int cont = 0;
    private List<V> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Graph(){
        adjacencyList = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public boolean addVertex(V v){
        if(adjacencyList.containsKey(v)) {
            return false;
        }else {
            Set<V> vList = new HashSet<>();
            adjacencyList.put(v, vList);
            cont++;
            lista.add(v);
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public int nArray(V v1, List<V> l) {
        int num = 0;
        if(l.contains(v1)) {
            for(int i = 0; i<l.size(); i++) {
                if(v1 == l.get(i)) {
                    num=i;
                    i=l.size();
                }
            }
        }
        return num;
        

        
    }
    
    public boolean addEdge(V v1, V v2){
        if(adjacencyList.containsKey(v1) && adjacencyList.containsKey(v2)){
            adjacencyList.get(v1).add(v2);
            return false;
        }else {
            if(!(adjacencyList.containsKey(v1)) && !(adjacencyList.containsKey(v2))){
                this.addVertex(v1);
                this.addVertex(v2);
                adjacencyList.get(v1).add(v2);          
            }else {
                if(!(adjacencyList.containsKey(v1))) {
                    this.addVertex(v1);
                    adjacencyList.get(v1).add(v2);
                }else {
                    this.addVertex(v2);
                    adjacencyList.get(v1).add(v2);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public Set<V> obtainAdjacents(V v) throws Exception{
        return adjacencyList.get(v);
    }
    
    public boolean containsVertex(V v){
        if(adjacencyList.containsKey(v)) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public List<V> onePath(V v1, V v2){
        int iter = 0;
        if(!adjacencyList.containsKey(v1)){
            System.out.println(v1 + " No existe");
            this.addVertex(v1);
            return null;
        }else {
            if(!adjacencyList.containsKey(v2)){
                System.out.println(v2 + " No existe");
                this.addVertex(v2);
                return null;
            }else {
                if(adjacencyList.containsKey(v2) && adjacencyList.containsKey(v1)){
                    List<V> lista = new ArrayList<>();
                    lista.add(v1);
                    for(int i = 1; i<cont; i++) {
                        if(!(adjacencyList.get(i).isEmpty()) || !(adjacencyList.get(i) == null)) {
                            List<V> vList = new ArrayList<>(adjacencyList.get(i));
                            if(vList.contains(v2)) {
                                lista.add(v2);
                                i = cont;
                            }else {
                                for(int j = iter; j<vList.size(); j++) {
                                    if(adjacencyList.containsKey(vList.get(j))) {
                                        lista.add(vList.get(j));
                                        if(vList.get(j) == v2) {
                                            i=cont;
                                        }
                                        i=this.nArray(vList.get(i), vList);
                                        iter++;
                                        j = vList.size();

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return lista;
                }
                    
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return "" + adjacencyList + "";
    }


    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
    }


}
```

Comment: Usa un algoritmo de tipo primero el mejor

Comment: @Japv que tipo de algoritmo es ese?

Comment: Puedes investigar en internet, también se conoce como algoritmos ávidos o voraces,